# The students $S_1, S_2,...S_{10}$ are divided into 3 groups A, B and C

Tags: permutations

It can be seen as distributing n unique objects above m groups

> The students $S_1, S_2,...S_{10}$ are divided into 3 groups A, B and C such that each group has at least one students and C has at most 3. Find possibilities of forming groups

$$a+b+c=10$$

The number of positive integral solutions $(\ge 1)$ is
$$\binom {10-1}{3-1}=36$$

I don’t know how to account for the cases where C has at most 3 students

Also I know this method of solving is probably wrong but I don’t know how else to do it.

Comment: "almost 3". How is it?!

Comment: @user most likely $atmost$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving aside group $C$, each student has $2$ choices for groups

Group $C$ can receive a student in $\binom{10}1$ ways.

The remaining students could be received by the other two groups in $2^9$ ways, but this could result in one group receiving no student.

Any of the two groups could be empty, so we subtract $2$ to get legal ways as

$\binom{10}1\cdot (2^9-2)$, and proceeding similarly with group $C$ having $2$ or $3$ students, and adding up, we get

$\binom{10}1\cdot (2^9-2) + \binom{10}2\cdot(2^8-2) +\binom{10}3\cdot(2^7-2) = 31650$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the simplest way is to consider the problem by cases. There are only 3 options:
$$
c=1,2,3.
$$

The second issue is that you are asked not about the number of ways to choose the size of groups but to distribute the students between them. For example for $c=1$ the number is
$$
\binom{10}1\sum_{i=1}^8\binom9i=\binom{10}1(2^9-2)
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: user--- Are you saying it's easy as 1,2,3? :-)

Comment: @coffeemath  I am saying $c=1$ or $c=2$ or $c=3$. :)

Comment: Yes maybe I shouldn't have left a comment which is only a jest... Don't want to confuse the question asker...

Comment: I think your comment was very useful for clarifying the issue.

Comment: Ok, so then what would give an equation with a and b, after which we just use the method I used above?

Comment: That will give $8+7+6=21$ but the correct answer is 31650

Comment: @Aditya I have added the next step. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don’t understand how you got that. What are you using exactly?

Comment: @Aditya I was using $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni=2^n$.

Comment: No I meant theoretically, what did you use? Like how did you get the expression with the coefficients?

Comment: I count the numbers of ways to choose a student for the group $C $ and then those to choose $i $ students (from the 9 remaining) for the group A. The rest goes to the group B.